# Intermittent Selenium ECONNREFUSED errors on CircleCI

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, circleci

Our CircleCI tests use selenium, via the selenium-webdriver to run UI tests through PhantomJS. The tests work 100% of the time locally in our vagrant env, but fail about 1 out of 3 times on CircleCI with ECONNREFUSED errors like:

```
   Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 10.0.4.1:59525
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:238:15)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
      at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/public/login.php?t=ur&ign=1&ut=ad)
      at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
      at Navigation.to (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1140:25)
      at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:997:28)
      at User.logIn (testJs/ui/utils/user.js:9:16)
      at Host.logInAsHost (testJs/ui/utils/host.js:13:14)
      at Preferences.disableRevenueGeneration (testJs/ui/utils/preferences.js:57:14)
      at Context.<anonymous> (testJs/ui/tests/preferences.js:13:22)
```

These errors happen at random times throughout our tests and they are not being triggered by any particular place in our tests. As far as I can tell, this issue is occurring on the selenium/selenium-webdriver end as the web server remains up and working and isn't generating any errors.

I’ve tried all of the following and none of them have worked:

1. Upgraded to the latest selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
2. Upgraded to a more recent version of nodejs (6.9.2)
3. Used a different web server
4. Upgraded to a recent version of PhantomJS (1.9.7-15)
5. Tried using `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` as per
   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87
6. In node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js, I modified the code to retry for ECONNREFUSED errors by reusing the retry already there for ECONNRESET, i.e. `if (e.code === 'ECONNRESET') {` becomes `if (e.code === 'ECONNRESET' || e.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {`. This doesn’t work as then selenium-webdriver just retries indefinitely and from this I realized that the issue appears to be that once an ECONNREFUSED error is encountered, selenium/selenium-webdriver are unrecoverable.

Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING: This is merely a hack and is by no means a proper solution, but it is the only one that appears to reliably work for us on CircleCI. Hopefully, someone else will find a better solution.**

Our test framework, mocha, appears to have a retry mechanism developed specifically for selenium (go figure): http://mochajs.org/#retry-tests. The first gotcha is that code in `after` and `before` is not retried. Therefore, you need to move code to `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. The second gotcha is that you need some special logic in `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to handle driver errors.

So, in order to utilize this mechanism, we had to refactor our tests so that each test has a `beforeEach` that sets up a fresh webdriver instance and then an `afterEach` that quits that driver instance. This way, a crashed driver instance doesn’t stop all subsequent tests. We developed a helper function that we call at the beginning of all `describe` blocks so that we don’t have to add too much code to our tests.

Then, we added `this.retries(10)` to our topmost `describe` block.

Here is the helper class:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

// We default to using phantomjs, but in the future, when we run tests in other browsers, e.g. via
// SauceLabs, we'll want to change the browser.
var customPhantom = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
customPhantom.set('ssl-protocol', 'any');

// For convenience in tests
global.By = webdriver.By;
global.until = webdriver.until;

var SeleniumStabilizer = function () {};

SeleniumStabilizer.prototype.MAX_RETRIES = 10;

SeleniumStabilizer.prototype.createDriver = function () {
    global.driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        // .forBrowser('phantomjs')
        .withCapabilities(customPhantom)
        .build();

    // Resolves when driver is ready
    return global.driver;
};

SeleniumStabilizer.prototype.init = function (opts) {

    var self = this,
        n = 0;

    var beforeEachWithRetries = function () {
        // Create a fresh selenium driver for the next test
        return self.createDriver().then(function () {
            if (opts.onBeforeEach) {
                // Execute the test-specific defined onBeforeEach
                return opts.onBeforeEach();
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // ECONNREFUSED error and we should retry?
            if (err.message.indexOf('ECONNREFUSED') !== -1 && n++ < self.MAX_RETRIES) {
                return beforeEachWithRetries();
            } else {
                throw err;              
            }
        });
    };

    opts.beforeEach(function () {
        n = 0;
        return beforeEachWithRetries();
    });

    var afterEachWithRetries = function () {
        return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            if (opts.onAfterEach) {
                // Execute the test-specific defined onAfterEach
                return opts.onAfterEach();
            }
        }).then(function () {
            // Quit the selenium driver before starting the next test
            return driver.quit();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // ECONNREFUSED error and we should retry?
            if (err.message.indexOf('ECONNREFUSED') !== -1 && n++ < self.MAX_RETRIES) {
                // Create a new driver
                return self.createDriver().then(function () {
                    return afterEachWithRetries();
                });
            } else {
                throw err;              
            }
        });
    };

    opts.afterEach(function () {
        n = 0;
        return afterEachWithRetries();
    });
};
```

Then, your tests look like:

```
var seleniumStabilizer = new SeleniumStabilizer();

describe('my tests', function () {

  this.retries(seleniumStabilizer.MAX_RETRIES);

  describe('search engines', function () {

    seleniumStabilizer.init({
      beforeEach: beforeEach,
      afterEach: afterEach,
      onBeforeEach: function () {
        // e.g. return doPromiseAfterDriverSetUp();
      },
      onAfterEach: function () {
        // e.g. return doPromiseBeforeDriverQuits();
      }
    });

    it('should get google', function () {
      return driver.get('https://www.google.com');
    });

    it('should get amazon', function () {
      return driver.get('https://www.amazon.com');
    });

  });

});
```